# how to add a container to service in stack via rancher REST api

Tags: rest, rancher

I'm trying to create and add a container to an already existing service in rancher using the rancher REST api.

I would expect that the following request would create a container and add it to the atlas-mosquitto stack and the mosquitto service (see labels).

```
curl -u "${RANCHER_ACCESS_KEY}:${RANCHER_SECRET_KEY}" \
-X POST \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{"count":1, "imageUuid":"docker:dummy/atlas/mosquitto:0.0.8", "name":"atlas-mosquitto_mosquitto_dummy_name", "startOnCreate":true, "labels": {"io.rancher.service.deployment.unit": "acdaf002-e1d0-4625-ba9c-3e1dbc584a14", "io.rancher.project.name": "atlas-mosquitto", "io.rancher.container.pull_image": "always", "io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:container_label_soft_ne": "io.rancher.stack_service.name=atlas-mosquitto/mosquitto", "io.rancher.service.launch.config": "io.rancher.service.primary.launch.config", "io.rancher.project_service.name": "atlas-mosquitto/mosquitto", "io.rancher.stack.name": "atlas-mosquitto", "io.rancher.stack_service.name": "atlas-mosquitto/mosquitto"},  "publishAllPorts":false, "privileged":false, "stdinOpen":false, "tty":false, "readOnly":false' \
'https://rancher-ha.dummy.info/v1/projects/1a29/containers'
```

below is a pretty print of the body for easy readability:

```
{
  "count": 1,
  "imageUuid": "docker:dummy\/atlas\/mosquitto:0.0.8",
  "name": "atlas-mosquitto_mosquitto_dummy_name",
  "startOnCreate": true,
  "labels": {
    "io.rancher.service.deployment.unit": "acdaf002-e1d0-4625-ba9c-3e1dbc584a14",
    "io.rancher.project.name": "atlas-mosquitto",
    "io.rancher.container.pull_image": "always",
    "io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:container_label_soft_ne": "io.rancher.stack_service.name=atlas-mosquitto\/mosquitto",
    "io.rancher.service.launch.config": "io.rancher.service.primary.launch.config",
    "io.rancher.project_service.name": "atlas-mosquitto\/mosquitto",
    "io.rancher.stack.name": "atlas-mosquitto",
    "io.rancher.stack_service.name": "atlas-mosquitto\/mosquitto"
  },
  "publishAllPorts": false,
  "privileged": false,
  "stdinOpen": false,
  "tty": false,
  "readOnly": false
}
```

below is the response:

```
{
   "readOnly" : false,
   "created" : "2016-12-07T01:15:04Z",
   "memory" : null,
   "securityOpt" : null,
   "createIndex" : null,
   "logConfig" : null,
   "state" : "creating",
   "links" : {
      "serviceExposeMaps" : "https://rancher-ha.dummy.info/v1/projects/1a29/containers/1i9139/serviceexposemaps",
      "healthcheckInstanceHostMaps" : "https://rancher-ha.dummy.info/v1/projects/1a29/containers/1i9139/healthcheckinstancehostmaps",
      "instances" : "https://rancher-ha.dummy.info/v1/projects/1a29/containers/1i9139/instances",
      "services" : "https://rancher-ha.dummy.info/v1/projects/1a29/containers/1i9139/services",
      "ports" : "https://rancher-ha.dummy.info/v1/projects/1a29/containers/1i9139/ports",
      "hosts" : "https://rancher-ha.dummy.info/v1/projects/1a29/containers/1i9139/hosts",
      "instanceLinks" : "https://rancher-ha.dummy.info/v1/projects/1a29/containers/1i9139/instancelinks",
      "credentials" : "https://rancher-ha.dummy.info/v1/projects/1a29/containers/1i9139/credentials",
      "volumes" : "https://rancher-ha.dummy.info/v1/projects/1a29/containers/1i9139/volumes",
      "account" : "https://rancher-ha.dummy.info/v1/projects/1a29/containers/1i9139/account",
      "serviceEvents" : "https://rancher-ha.dummy.info/v1/projects/1a29/containers/1i9139/serviceevents",
      "stats" : "https://rancher-ha.dummy.info/v1/projects/1a29/containers/1i9139/stats",
      "mounts" : "https://rancher-ha.dummy.info/v1/projects/1a29/containers/1i9139/mounts",
      "targetInstanceLinks" : "https://rancher-ha.dummy.info/v1/projects/1a29/containers/1i9139/targetinstancelinks",
      "self" : "https://rancher-ha.dummy.info/v1/projects/1a29/containers/1i9139",
      "instanceLabels" : "https://rancher-ha.dummy.info/v1/projects/1a29/containers/1i9139/instancelabels",
      "containerStats" : "https://rancher-ha.dummy.info/v1/projects/1a29/containers/1i9139/containerstats"
   },
   "labels" : {
      "io.rancher.container.pull_image" : "always",
      "io.rancher.project.name" : "atlas-mosquitto",
      "io.rancher.stack.name" : "atlas-mosquitto",
      "io.rancher.stack_service.name" : "atlas-mosquitto/mosquitto",
      "io.rancher.service.deployment.unit" : "acdaf002-e1d0-4625-ba9c-3e1dbc584a14",
      "io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:container_label_soft_ne" : "io.rancher.stack_service.name=atlas-mosquitto/mosquitto",
      "io.rancher.service.launch.config" : "io.rancher.service.primary.launch.config",
      "io.rancher.project_service.name" : "atlas-mosquitto/mosquitto"
   },
   "dnsSearch" : null,
   "startCount" : 0,
   "privileged" : false,
   "workingDir" : null,
   "id" : "1i9139",
   "uuid" : "bc64996c-4a9f-40bd-91bc-e352d84604aa",
   "transitioningProgress" : null,
   "lxcConf" : null,
   "hostId" : null,
   "pidMode" : null,
   "transitioningMessage" : "In Progress",
   "requestedHostId" : null,
   "dataVolumes" : null,
   "startOnCreate" : true,
   "domainName" : null,
   "volumeDriver" : null,
   "cpuSet" : null,
   "restartPolicy" : null,
   "networkContainerId" : null,
   "user" : null,
   "dataVolumeMounts" : null,
   "nativeContainer" : false,
   "deploymentUnitUuid" : null,
   "hostname" : null,
   "tty" : false,
   "capDrop" : null,
   "name" : "atlas-mosquitto_mosquitto_2",
   "removed" : null,
   "primaryIpAddress" : null,
   "cpuShares" : null,
   "imageUuid" : "docker:distribution.dummy.info/atlas/mosquitto:0.0.8",
   "createdTS" : 1481073304000,
   "systemContainer" : null,
   "environment" : {
      "AUTH_SERVICE_ALIAS" : "auth.atlas-auth.rancher.internal",
      "AUTH_SERVICE_PORT" : "8100"
   },
   "stdinOpen" : false,
   "accountId" : "1a29",
   "registryCredentialId" : null,
   "description" : "foo",
   "command" : null,
   "version" : "0",
   "build" : null,
   "healthCheck" : null,
   "expose" : null,
   "entryPoint" : null,
   "publishAllPorts" : false,
   "memorySwap" : null,
   "type" : "container",
   "dataVolumesFrom" : null,
   "actions" : {
      "error" : "https://rancher-ha.dummy.info/v1/projects/1a29/containers/1i9139/?action=error",
      "remove" : "https://rancher-ha.dummy.info/v1/projects/1a29/containers/1i9139/?action=remove",
      "stop" : "https://rancher-ha.dummy.info/v1/projects/1a29/containers/1i9139/?action=stop",
      "setlabels" : "https://rancher-ha.dummy.info/v1/projects/1a29/containers/1i9139/?action=setlabels",
      "start" : "https://rancher-ha.dummy.info/v1/projects/1a29/containers/1i9139/?action=start"
   },
   "blkioDeviceOptions" : null,
   "externalId" : null,
   "healthState" : null,
   "kind" : "container",
   "ports" : null,
   "extraHosts" : null,
   "devices" : null,
   "networkMode" : "managed",
   "capAdd" : null,
   "dns" : null,
   "firstRunning" : null,
   "transitioning" : "yes"
}
```

based on this response and this label `"io.rancher.project_service.name" : "atlas-mosquitto/mosquitto"`, I would expect the container to be in that service, however it is not. The container is created, but it ends up being created as a standalone container. What I want is for this created container to be DNS addressable and accessible in rancher UI under the specified stack and service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok problem solved. to add a container to a specific stack/service you must first modify the service you want the container to be added to. The service needs to have the tag `io.rancher.service.selector.container`

for example, let's say I want the REST API created container to be added to my mosquitto service. The docker-compose file for the mosquitto service might look something like this:

```
moquitto:
  image: distribution.foofee.com/atlas/mosquitto:0.0.23
  environment:
    AUTH_SERVICE_PORT: 8100
    AUTH_SERVICE_ALIAS: auth.atlas-auth.rancher.internal
  labels:
    io.rancher.service.selector.container: stackz=mos-test
```

take a closer look at `io.rancher.service.selector.container: stackz=mos-test`. This tells rancher to add all containers with the label `stackz=mos-test` to the mosquitto service.

Now that we've specified this, we can create our container via the rancher REST API using a request like this:

```
curl -u "${RANCHER_ACCESS_KEY}:${RANCHER_SECRET_KEY}" \
-X POST \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{"count":1, "imageUuid":"docker:distribution.foo.com/atlas/mosquitto:0.0.23", "name":"foozy", "startOnCreate":true, "command":[], "publishAllPorts":false, "privileged":false, "stdinOpen":false, "tty":false, "restartPolicy":null, "readOnly":false, "build":null, "networkMode":"managed", "labels": {"stackz": "mos-test", "io.rancher.container.network": "true", "io.rancher.container.dns": "true"}}' \
'https://rancher.us-west-2.foo.com/v1/projects/1a5/containers'
```

pretty printed body:

```
{
  "count": 1,
  "imageUuid": "docker:distribution.foo.com\/atlas\/mosquitto:0.0.23",
  "name": "foozy",
  "startOnCreate": true,
  "command": [

  ],
  "publishAllPorts": false,
  "privileged": false,
  "stdinOpen": false,
  "tty": false,
  "restartPolicy": null,
  "readOnly": false,
  "build": null,
  "networkMode": "managed",
  "labels": {
    "stackz": "mos-test",
    "io.rancher.container.network": "true",
    "io.rancher.container.dns": "true"
  }
}
```

since we've added the label `"stackz": "mos-test"` in this request, this adds the container to the mosquitto because this label matches with the `io.rancher.service.selector.container` label we set on the mosquitto service.

the container is also now directly DNS addressable from anywhere in the rancher environment. The container created from the above request is named foozy. It is DNS addressable as `foozy.rancher.internal`